# What is the minimum bandwidth for playing StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

The official StarCraft II System Requirements says "Broadband Internet connection".

But how many kbps are required for playing online?

Comment: If you're having trouble, try out http://www.battleping.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1mbit minimum or 3mbit recommended:

[Source](http://www.sc2blog.com/2008/05/22/starcraft-2-system-requirements-revealed/)

Also note that latency is usually more important than bandwidth.

Comment: Thats from 22 May 2008, I don't know if its still relevant. I know people are playing with 512kbps, but I have only 256kbps.

Comment: @hiena, the game definately requires less than that, your latency is way more important.

Answer (score 0):

Games rarely require more than few KB/s.

The latency and stability is much more important. If you are getting more than 150 ms or dropping more than 5% of packets, then it might be a problem.